# Elasticsearch show only the name of all indices with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, ejs

I am using ejs framework with node js. I can get all the index names in json format. But what I want is just the names of the indices. My code looks like as follows-

```
var client = require('../routes/Connection.js');

//display all indexes
module.exports.allIndexes = function (searchData, callback) {
    client.indices.getAliases({
        index: "_all",
        level: "indices"
    }, function (error, response, status) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("search error: " + error)
        }
        else {
            //callback(response);---> this works
            callback(response.hits.hits); // ---> this doesn't
        }
    });
}
```

if I use response in callback, I get the following output:

```
{
  "index-1": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "index-2": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "index-3": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "index-4": {
    "aliases": {}
  }
}
```

and when I use response.hits.hits in callback I get the error:"cannot read property 'hits' of undefined". I want to show only the index names as a list. FYI, in front end, I passed the response say as "results" :

```
        <h1>Index</h1>
        <% for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) { %>
          <%= results[i].indices %>
        <% } %>
```

which shows nothing ofcourse.

edit_1:

I import the module as follows:
in my `index.js`:

```
router.post('/indexes', function (req, res) {
    elasticModule.allIndexes(req.body, function (data) {
        res.render('elasticGui', { title: 'Elasticsearch GUI', results: data });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where do you import the first module? Show us how you do it.

Comment: Also check for `response.errors` property in your response argument.

Comment: @jstice4all I have edited my question and added that, please have a look, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at your response structure

```
{
  "index-1": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "index-2": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "index-3": {
    "aliases": {}
  },
  "index-4": {
    "aliases": {}
  }
}
```

you don't see any `hits`, do you? So `response.hits` is undefined and the error happens when trying to reference `hits` out of `response.hits`

You simply need to change your code like this:

```
callback(Object.keys(response));
```

And then in your view you can iterate over that array like this:

```
    <% results.forEach(function(index) { %>
      <%= index %>
    <% }); %>
```